# NHibernate Cache PrevalenceProvider strange behavior

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-caches

I'm using NH Prevalence Cache provider with happiness from years, but recently, my team, started to fall in some data 
incorrectness which I can't yet explain...

We setup the prevalence by setting up the cache provider and 
setting the prevalenceBase folder to AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
setting a default expiration of 120

each cache registration in mappings ha a region name

The cache seems to work, but if the application is recycled, the data which will be returned by NHibernate is incorrect
with a valid identifier, it provides data which seems owned by another entity.
If we delete the .snapshot file in the folder (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory) then everything starts to work fine, 
until the next recycle wher ethe issue will be represented.

Any one has got the same issue?
Any one can help with this issue?

Sure I forget or ignore something, but someone who can explain better how to setup prevalence will be appreciated
Thanks in advance